# Mapping process and mapped file have different Team IDs

Tags: libraries, sandbox, notarize

macOS 10.14.5 --> Sorry my Catalina is in quarantine at work!
Xcode 11.2.1

com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation does not behave as documented.

My test application is X11 (XQuartz) based and thus needs libraries from /opt/X11/ and /usr/lib/ which have a different team ID from mine.

The app contains a C binary which and works calls "winteracter" a small FORTRAN binary which displays an X11 window and dialogue. "winteracter" is signed/hardened/sandboxed (inherit) before importing to Xcode. It is placed in the Resources folder but placing it in MacOS makes no difference.

The entitlements are as follows:
Main application:

```
<key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only</key>
<array>
    <string>/opt/X11/lib/</string>
    <string>/usr/lib/</string>
</array>
```

Auxiliary binaries:

```
<key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
<true/>
```

The application successfully notarizes (thus signing, hardening and sandboxing are Okay)
High Sierra: It works. Mojave: it gives the runtime error (Console:error+fault+winteracter):

```
Library Validation failed: Rejecting '/opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib' (Team ID: NA574AWV7E, platform: no) for process 'winteracter(11592)' (Team ID: P65398CN49, platform: no), reason: mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) **have different Team IDs**
```

This is odd for two reasons:
1- the rejection of different team IDs contradicts with Apple's description of "disable-library-validation"
2- december 2019 I got a functional notarized application by simply using the command line codesign with "-o runtime". This no longer works.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: I think you need to set the entitlement `<key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>` to `true` too

Comment: No this is not necessary. The trick is that the X11 binary must be codesigned from outside Xcode. My application is now notarized and functional but I spent a week in writing a test application, scripts, fighting with Xcode, etc. What still fails is the sandboxing.

Answer (score 2):

Here a more detailed description of my solution.

I finally found a solution to obtain a notarised application which is functional.
The bundle is organised as follows:

```
  TestApp.app
     Contents
        MacOS
           testAppp  <--  a launcher (C binary)
           myAlert     <-- an alert dialogue (Cocoa binary)
        Resources
           winteracter <-- an X11 (Xquartz) window and dialogue (Fortran binary)
```

The binary "winteracter" is based on the Winteracter library <http://www.winteracter.com> which uses OpenMotif and Xquartz

**winteracter** binary

This binary is hardened manually (i.e. from outside Xcode) prior to the others:

```
codesign -d --force --options runtime --verbose=4 -s "$DEV_CERTIFICATE" --entitlements "winteracter.entitlements" "winteracter"
```

winteracter.entitlements should only contain the following key:

```
<key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
<true>
```

**testApp** and **myAlert** binaries

These are signed and hardened either manually:

```
codesign -d --force --options runtime --verbose=4 -s "$DEV_CERTIFICATE" "$MYBINARY"
```

or using Xcode:

```
In that case be sure to manually erase the field "*Code Signing Entitlements*" in Build Settings.
```

It may remain filled in even if you delete "Sandboxing" from the Capabilities interface.

Once notarized the application is functional.
I tried sandboxing it but the infamous error "*mapping process and mapped file (non-platform) have different Team IDs*" went back !

But what were my mistakes?

1- Apple says that sandboxing keys must appear only once in the entitlement file of the main binary, with others having only the "inherit" key. I wrongly assumed that com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation was inherited too.

2- I thought the key com.apple.security.app-sandbox was compulsory in entitlement files. Not at all!

3- I wrongly assumed that setting com.apple.security.app-sandbox to false is equivalent to no entitlement file. Wrong again!

4- I wrongly assumed that the Xcode interface "Signing & Capabilities" correctly manages the Build Settings.

5- I performed so many trial an errors that I do not remember all by all dead ends where I got lost.

Comment: I run into this when running Godot from shell reporting OBS Virtual Cam "not valid for use in process using Library Validation" when `dlopen(/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/obs-mac-virtualcam.plugin/Contents/MacOS/obs-mac-virtualcam, 262)` both are just installed applications.